# Serial Number for dynamic table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, serialization

I have a dynamic table which has 2 dynamic rows .i.e students and their subjects and marks. The code is below :

[**Click here to view the code**](https://jsfiddle.net/soumyar/ou6sz83u/)

> **Code for Serial Number**

```
 function numberRows() {
      $('input[name^="SNo"]').each(function(i) {
            $(this).val(i + 1);
      });
        }
    numberRows();
```

> **Output that comes :**

[image]

> **Output expected**

[image]

The serial numbers are not generated dynamically. Where could I have possibly gone wrong? Would appreciate any help/ suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling function

```
 numberRows();
```

after return statement. Either update logic or call it at the after processing return call. Like - https://jsfiddle.net/jqus6bmw/

Comment: Thanks a million! :)